# C++ sorting vector objects error

Tags: c++, sorting

Sorry for posting a duplicate post but I have my best to find the answer around still couldnt solve the error. I follow many example but it just doesnt seem to work. I having problem with sorting a vector of object.

Its giving me a whole chunk of error on that line of code with sort which i cant even debug.
When i comment out that line it running fine without error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//some other codes

vector<PointTwoD> Point;

bool sortByCiv(PointTwoD &d1, PointTwoD &d2) { 
    return d1.getCivIndex() < d2.getCivIndex(); 
}


void print_top5()

{

    int num = 0;;
    cout << "Total no. of records available = " << Point.size() << endl;

    cout << "Prining top 5 explorations destinations..." << endl;
    **sort(Point.begin(), Point.end(), sortByCiv);**
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

    {
        num++;
        int x, y;
        float civ;
        x = Point[i].getX();
        y = Point[i].getY();
        civ = Point[i].getCivIndex();
        if (civ > 0){    
            cout<< num << " Civ Index :" << civ << " at sector (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
        } else {
            cout<< num << " <no other records available>" << endl;
        }


    }

}
```

I am able to print out the results nicely in the for loop, i just need it to be in descending order. Thanks a lot.

this is the error message

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from MissionPlan.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >; _Tp = PointTwoD; _Compare = bool (*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2296:78:   required from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >; _Compare = bool (*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2337:62:   required from ‘void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >; _Size = long int; _Compare = bool (*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5490:44:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PointTwoD*, std::vector<PointTwoD> >; _Compare = bool (*)(PointTwoD&, PointTwoD&)]’
MissionPlan.cpp:33:44:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2263:35: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘PointTwoD&’ from expression of type ‘const PointTwoD’
    while (__comp(*__first, __pivot))
                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2266:34: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘PointTwoD&’ from expression of type ‘const PointTwoD’
    while (__comp(__pivot, *__last))
```

Comment: How about `return d1.getCivIndex() > d2.getCivIndex()`

Comment: Can you tell us what the "whole chunk of error" is you are getting?

Comment: @Brandon just updated the error msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first - this is not a minimum compilable example. If you could publish something we can compile (say here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) it would help a lot.

Having said that, your comparison function should take arguments by const reference. In addition, in order to sort in descending order you'd need to change the logic of the predicate as follows:

```
bool sortByCiv(const PointTwoD &d1, const PointTwoD &d2) { 
    return d1.getCivIndex() > d2.getCivIndex(); 
}
```

edit:

Have a look at this link - this code compiles and you can use it as a reference.

http://goo.gl/kUVP5r

Comment: The function does not need to take its parameters as `const`, but it should not modify them.

Comment: MissionPlan.cpp: In function ‘bool sortByCiv(const PointTwoD&, const PointTwoD&)’:
MissionPlan.cpp:25:24: error: passing ‘const PointTwoD’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘float PointTwoD::getCivIndex()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  return d1.getCivIndex() > d2.getCivIndex();

Comment: Well, I guess the library DOES require the parameters to be `const`.

Comment: Also, `getCivIndex()` needs to be const.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano u mean when i implement them in my header and cpp file?

Comment: Alternatively, the method can take its parameters by value (and thus not need to be const): `bool sortByCiv(PointTwoD d1, PointTwoD d2)`

Comment: In this case, it's better to take them as `const &`. The member function should be defined like `getCivIndex() const { ... }`.